# Get all associated categories from product collection

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, product-collection, category-products

For a custom filter on the product collection i need to be able to get all associated categories from all products from the catalog search result. On top of that, i do not need the actual categories the products are in, but their 3th lvl parent to make it even more complicated.

I'd prefer a clean way over direct queries. Something like:

$_productCollection->getAssociatedCategories()

Is there any known build in method for this? I would like to avoid looping.

A direct query would work like this:

```
    SELECT t01.entity_id,t02.value AS `name`
    FROM catalog_category_entity t01
    LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity_varchar t02
    ON t01.entity_id = t02.entity_id AND t02.attribute_id = 41 AND t02.store_id = 0
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tt02.path, '/', 4), '/', -1) AS `entity_id` FROM catalog_category_product tt01
        LEFT JOIN catalog_category_entity tt02
        ON tt01.category_id = tt02.entity_id
        WHERE tt01.product_id IN (".$this->stringWithProductIds().")
        GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tt02.path, '/', 4), '/', -1)
    ) t03
    ON t01.entity_id = t03.entity_id
    WHERE t01.parent_id = ".$this->2ndLvlParent()."
    AND t03.entity_id IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY t02.value ASC
```